# Identify the components of this bike

Tags: wheels, parts, handlebars, identify-this-bike

I'm trying to identify, or find similar, parts on the bike in [this video](http://vimeo.com/18472550), specifically the front (three spoke) wheel, frame, and handle bars.

Comment: +1 - Best video. I noticed later that it's an ad, for a bag. Sadly my only criticism as I was watching it was, "the lad could use pannier."

Comment: Yes, fortunately the advertising is subtle enough to let you enjoy the great video and music :)

Comment: I'm not sure anyone will be able to identify the handlebars' make/model from a video, but if you're looking for the name of that style of handlebar, it's ["pursuit" or "bullhorn"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_handlebar#Pursuit). The wheel appears to be an [HED H3](http://www.hedcycling.com/h3/default.asp?content=H3_Tubular) or something similar.

Comment: Yea, I thought I might be pushing it a little there. I was really mostly interested in the wheels and the type of handle bars. I had no idea these would be in the $1400 range... Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes it's a beautiful ad. More about it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/bicycles).

Answer (score 1):

I looks like a Corima to me, but I may be wrong: http://www.corima.com/gb/produits/roues/default.cfm?family=roues_janteCorima for sale at http://www.lfgss.com/thread37288.html in plain black.

You're right about that being a nice ad - I like the video as well as the music.

Comment: They say that a haiku ought to identify or imply the place (e.g. "by a pond"), and the time (the season or the time of day): which that video really does.